# Reading a file using fixed number of bytes java

Tags: java, file, byte, filestream

I am writing a program to copy large files, so I want to read specific number of bytes and write to another file. I want to copy the file and get same number of bytes. But I am getting more. Plus I also want the contents of the file to remain same. What am I doing wrong here? If someone can explain why am I getting this extra text, that would be great.

test.txt

```
sometext sometext sometext sometext
sometext sometext sometext sometext
sometext sometext sometext sometext
sometext sometext sometext sometext
```

Practice.java

```
public class Practice{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

    try{
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("copy_test.txt");
        int b;
        while ((b=f.read(buffer)) != -1 )
            writer.write(new String(buffer));
        writer.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

copy_test.txt

```
sometext sometext sometext sometext
sometext sometext sometext sometext
sometext sometext sometext sometext
sometext sometext sometext sometext
metext sometext sometext
sometext sometext sometext
```

Comment: Erm, why don't you just use [`Files.copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)?

Comment: Also, you use an `InputStream` as a source and a `Writer` as destination? Huh? Basically you're reading apples but writing oranges.

Comment: @fge Because it;s just a sample code, actually I am transferring files from a server to a client. So I can't use Files.copy().

Comment: Depends on the server. The java.nio.file API allows `FileSystem`s over anything. [See here](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-ftp) for instance. And please notes that [`Files.copy()` can copy from an `InputStream` to a `Path` as well](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- You're using the default platform encoding to convert the binary data into text (by calling `new String(byte[])` instead of specifying an encoding
- You're using the default platform encoding to write the text out to disk (by using `FileWriter`)
- You're unconditionally converting the *whole* of your buffer into text, even if your read didn't fill it - you can fix that by using one of the `String` constructor overloads taking an offset and number of bytes, and passing `0` and `b` for arguments, although I wouldn't. Use a try-with-resources statement.
- You're not closing the input stream at all, and if an exception is thrown you're not closing the writer. Use a try-with-resources statement.
- You're catching `Exception` - that's usually a bad idea. Catch *specific* exceptions if you must; personally I have very few `catch` blocks - generally if something goes wrong, it's appropriate for that to abort the whole of the current operation. (There are cases where you can retry etc, of course.) I understand this may just be in your sample code here, and not in your real code.
- If you're just trying to copy a file, there's no reason to convert between binary and text at all - stick with input streams and output streams
- If you're just trying to copy a file, you can use [`Files.copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) to avoid having to write any code at all, assuming you're using Java 7. (And if you're not, you should be!)

If you just want to copy an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` (and you haven't got a utility library available - this is part of a *lot* of libraries) you can just use something like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: why buffer of size 1024?

Comment: @user3834119: Why not? It feels like a reasonable balance between memory usage and excessive IO, although there may well be buffering in the stream too. It's a somewhat arbitrary number - as was your 100, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet the `Files` library uses 8kb - maybe 1kb is a little small. Although with a smallish file it would most likely make absolutely no difference.

Comment: 1 kiB is too small, really. The page granularity on most modern architectures today is 8kiB.

Comment: @fge - the page granularity is not directly relevant.  We are talking about files here.  The problem with doing reads / writes using buffers that are too small is the overheads in doing syscalls and context switches.  But yes, 1kb is probably too small.

Comment: @StephenC it is relevant in the sense that you still write the contents into a page and read from a page (well, except if you use `sendfile(2)`). And yes, syscall overhead is there for you too.

Comment: @fge - *"...you still write the contents into a page and read from a page"*.  But how is that relevant to performance?  What difference does it make if the read / write granularity is a page size or less?  You still have the same amount of copying?  The file will be transferred to / from the buffer cache in multiples of a disk block ... irrespective of how big / small the reads and writes are.

Comment: @StephenC simple: cache thrashing. You are not alone on a page. You share it with other code. If you take too small a part of it you will compete for this page with all other code which touches it.

Comment: @fge - I'm not following your argument.  Are you talking about the page containing the array referenced by `buffer`?  What other code is are you competing with?  And ... if you increase the buffer size won't that actually *increase* the cache competition?  Or are you talking about TLB entries?

Comment: For the record, the info I have found suggests that the default page size on Linux (on x86 / x86_64) is 4k, not 8 k.